# POI corrupt xlsm file once XSSFWorkbook.createName is called

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My requirements is to create an `XSSFName` using `XSSFWorkbook.createName()`. My code is :

```
Name name = myworkbook.createName();
...
myworkbook.write(fos);
```

But I get this error from excel when I open it :

```
Excel found unreadable content in 'filename.xlsm'. Do you want to reciver the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.
```

I want to avoid this message.

I'm using org.apache.poi 3.14

My workbook is an instance of XSSFWorkbook, before I was using HSSFWorkbook and I did not have this problem. The implementation of createName is different from XSSF to HSSF.

There is other people having the same [issue](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/200812.mbox/%3Ce549125d0812130929j3ba4401fr5303ca73e9196b9f@mail.gmail.com%3E) but with an old version

Comment: You only create a `Name` without setting its `NameName` and `RefersToFormula`? What happens if you do that also? See examples in https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Name.html

Comment: I set the `NameName` and `setFunction(true)` but not the `RefersToFormula`, I'm I obliged to ? And what for ? I already saw them.

Comment: This exactly is the reason why we need complete informations of what is the requirement, not only parts and one line of code. My guess now: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54125

Comment: It's exactly the same problem !! Is there a way to do it with the first approach ?

Comment: Why? What is the need? To evaluate the UDF with POI? For this much more is necessary. See https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html